# How I make this input in react native customable?

Tags: react-native, expo

I need a verification input and want to make it like in this picture:

[image]

I know how to make it but not customable. Maybe I want to make 4 or 5.

I can make it like this

```
const input2 = useRef();
const input3 = useRef();
const input4 = useRef();
const input5 = useRef();

<TextInput onChangeText={(e) => (setText(e), input2.focus() ) } />
<TextInput ref={(input) => { input2 = input } } />
```

But then its hardcoded. How can I make it customable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [react-native-confirmation-code-field](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-confirmation-code-field) which is highly customizable.

Here is a basic example using `4 inputs` instead of `5`. In fact, you can use any number of inputs.

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState("")
  const ref = useBlurOnFulfill({ value, cellCount: 4 })
  const [props, getCellOnLayoutHandler] = useClearByFocusCell({
    value,
    setValue,
  })
  return (
     <SafeAreaView style={{ margin: 40, marginTop: 80 }}>
      <CodeField
        ref={ref}
        {...props}
        // Use `caretHidden={false}` when users can't paste a text value, because context menu doesn't appear
        value={value}
        onChangeText={setValue}
        cellCount={4}
        keyboardType="number-pad"
        textContentType="oneTimeCode"
        renderCell={({ index, symbol, isFocused }) => (
          <Text
            style={{
              width: 40,
              height: 40,
              lineHeight: 38,
              fontSize: 24,
              borderWidth: 2,
              borderColor: "#00000030",
              textAlign: "center",
            }}
            key={index}
            onLayout={getCellOnLayoutHandler(index)}>
            {symbol || (isFocused ? <Cursor /> : null)}
          </Text>
        )}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
```

In general this component is very customizable. You can render your own input components, etc.

The above code yields the following very simple output. Designing the exact same component as given in your picture boils to designing a custom cell inside the `render` function.

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me how I run a function when I wrote the last letter/number ?

Comment: You are setting the `value` itself with a single state in the `onChangeText` function, thus if the `value`s length is equal to `cellCount`, then the last cell as been filled.